# Minimum number of distinct entries to fill a matrix so that no two cols are the same

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix with entries from $\{1,2,...,k\}$.  What is the minimum $k$ (as a function of $m$ and $n$) needed so that we can fill $A$ where no two columns are identical.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

This looks like homework.

**Hint 1:** If there are $m$ rows and $k$ symbols, how many possible distinct columns are there?

**Hint 2:** If the answer to hint 1 must be greater then or equal to the actual number of columns $n$, what does this mean that $k$ must be greater than or equal to?

**Bonus hint:** How might you deal with a fractional answer to hint 2?